# I want excel to Automatically populate values based on the Data Validation Rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am preparing an Excel formula, where I have to populate values based on what the user selects.

If User selects monthly, then populate it in next 12 months. If user selects quarterly, then only populate in next 4 quarters.

See Pic 1, Here, user has selected Monthly installment, my formula is correctly populating in next 12 months.

[image: Pic 1 - Monthly installment]

But the issue I am getting is when user selects quarterly, my formula is populating it in next 4 months instead of next 4 quarters. See pic 2.

[image: Pic 2 Quarterly Installment]

I want my formula to populate values only in July 24, Oct24, Jan 25 & April 25 when user selects Quarterly installments.

Comment: I would use an if() to choose between a 12 month list or 4 quarter list, perhaps vlookup() or choose()

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like this, which you can edit to your situation:

[image]

Formula as text to allow you to copy it:

```
IF($B$3="12 Months",B22,IF(AND($B$3="4 Quarters",B10=B11),B22,""))
```

As you posted images, I was not going to try to reproduce your data.